How to combine the filters in streams to simplify
I have this following method that takes in a List of a CustomClass and performs filters using streams and returns at each step based on the result of the filter.
I was wondering if there was a way to simplify the code but combining the filters and statements together to make it more concise and efficient.
public String transform(List<CustomObject> listOfObjects) {

       listOfObjects = listOfObjects.stream()
            .filter(object -> object.objectType().equals("BUSINESS")).toList();

       // Primary check as all object should be of business type 
       // and if nothing exist we throw an exception
       if (listOfObjects.isEmpty()) {
           throw new RuntimeException("NO BUSINESS OBJECT FOUND");

       }

       // All objects are now of business type but we want them to be active
       List<CustomObject> listOfActiveObjects = listOfObjects.stream()
                     .filter(object -> object.objectStatus().equals("ACTIVE"))
                     .toList();

       // If no active object found just return the first business object sorted url

       if (listOfActiveObjects.isEmpty()) {
           return listOfObjects.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(CustomObject::url))
                .toList().get(0).getUrl();
       }

       // Active objects are present so now filtered with proper locale

       List<CustomObject> listOfActiveObjectsWithLocale = listOfActiveObjects.stream()
                    .filter(object -> object.locale().equals("en-US"))
                    .toList();

       // If no locale was found just return the first sorted business active url

       if (listOfActiveObjectsWithLocale.isEmpty()) {
           return listOfActiveObjects.stream()
                 .sorted(Comparator.comparing(CustomObject::url))
                 .toList().get(0).getUrl();
       }

       // All filters applied, so within these objects return the sorted business/active/locale url
       return listOfActiveObjectsWithLocale.stream()
              .sorted(Comparator.comparing(CustomObject::url))
              .toList().get(0).getUrl();
   }


Check for Business objekts first then sort by your priority
public static String transform(List<CustomObject> listOfObjects) {

    // Check if there are any "BUSINESS" objects in the list
    if (listOfObjects.stream().noneMatch(object -> object.objectType().equals("BUSINESS"))) {
        throw new RuntimeException("NO BUSINESS OBJECT FOUND");
    }

    // Sort the objects based on the desired criteria and return the first one
    return listOfObjects.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator
            .comparing((CustomObject object) -> !object.objectType().equals("BUSINESS")) // BUSINESS first
            .thenComparing(object -> !object.objectStatus().equals("ACTIVE")) // then ACTIVE
            .thenComparing(object -> !object.locale().equals("en-US")) // then locale en-US
            .thenComparing(CustomObject::getUrl) // finally by URL
        )
        .findFirst()
        .get()  // Since an element is guaranteed, we can safely call get()
        .getUrl();
}

Edit
The now deleted comment was refering to calling Optional.get() Since in the if condition we made sure that there is at least one Business object, I don't think it is bad. But if you prefer you can change it to something like
public String transform(List<CustomObject> listOfObjects) {

if (listOfObjects.stream().noneMatch(object -> object.objectType().equals("BUSINESS"))) {
    throw new RuntimeException("NO BUSINESS OBJECT FOUND");
}

return listOfObjects.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator
        .comparing((CustomObject object) -> !object.objectType().equals("BUSINESS"))
        .thenComparing(object -> !object.objectStatus().equals("ACTIVE"))
        .thenComparing(object -> !object.locale().equals("en-US"))
        .thenComparing(CustomObject::url)
    )
    .findFirst()
    .map(CustomObject::getUrl)
    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Unexpected error during transformation"));
}


This works! Thank you! But i think as the above commentor mentioned it would be much better to combine the exception with the return statement instead of using get()

@Saad edited my answer

You can try this.
     listOfObjects.stream()
            .filter(object -> object.objectType().equals("BUSINESS"))
            .min(
                Comparator.<CustomObject, Boolean>comparing(object -> object.getObjectStatus().equals("ACTIVE"))
                    .thenComparing(object -> object.getLocale().equals("en-US"))
                    .thenComparing(CustomObject::getUrl)
            )
            .map(CustomObject::getUrl)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("NO BUSINESS OBJECT FOUND"));


wow! thanks! But it doesnt seem to be passing the case where only BUSINESS is present and the second filter does not pass. It should just sort without filtering. For below i am getting zbc.com when i am expecting jsdf.com
    listOfObjs.add(new CustomObject("https://www.jsdf.com", "BUSINESS",  "NOACTIVE", "en-US"));
    listOfObjs.add(new CustomObject("https://www.zbc.com", "BUSINESS", "NOACTIVE", "en-US"));


You may need to reverse some of comarators.

I think i fixed your that problem.

Thanks man! But Now it fails another test! Which is when no locale passes such as
    listOfObjs.add(new CustomObject("https://www.jsdf.com", "BUSINESS",  "ACTIVE", "en-BR"));
    listOfObjs.add(new CustomObject("https://www.ddddeee.com", "NO-BUSINESS",  "ACTIVE", "pl-PL"));
    listOfObjs.add(new CustomObject("https://www.mmmm.com", "BUSINESS",  "ACTIVE", "no-locale"));
    listOfObjs.add(new CustomObject("https://www.test.com", "BUSINESS", "NOACTIVE", "en-US"));


Its considering test.com above when it should not because its NOACTIVE

I think I fixed it. Check again.
